# linked list add at end not working

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been trying to add a node at end in a singly linked list but only the first element is added. What am doing wrong?

```
void addAtEnd(int key){
Node * head = Node;
if(head == NULL){
    head = new Node;
    head->key = key;
    head->next = NULL;
}
else{
    Node * current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }
    if(current == NULL){
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = NULL;
        current = temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Node * head = Node;` what does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add elements to the end of a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384407/how-to-add-elements-to-the-end-of-a-linked-list). Basically your while loop should be `while (current->next != NULL)`, and also delete the following `if`, or change to the (pointless) `if (current->next == NULL)`. And, of course, address the issue pointed out by @LuchianGrigore.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really assigned the value back to the `Node` field. By the way the name is really confusing, consider naming it `node` to avoid class with the class name.

Secondly the loop for finding the last element is wrong as it should be `current->next != NULL`).

In C/C++ it could be even more simplified with double pointer and you could get rid of `if-else` completely. In that case both the previous paragraphs become not valid as both the assignment and check would become part of the pointer dereference:

```
Node **currentPointer = &node; /* or head or however you name the field head */

while (*currentPointer != NULL) {
    currentPointer = &(*currentPointer)->next;
}
Node *temp = new Node;
temp->key = key;
temp->next = NULL;
*currentPointer = temp;
```